# Looping list of dictionaries and compare any matched values in other list

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a list of dictionaries and I am trying to loop and need to check `'pmdruleid'` in the `rulenames` matches any of the `'pmdruleid'` in `activeclientrulelist`. I am using below code and am getting `None` every time. The below code checks corresponding index value in the loop instead of checking any matching values in list:

```
activeclientrulelist = [{'pmdruleid': 112, 'createdby': 'Ad hoc Script - PHARMMD\\Jake.Woods', 'updatedby': None, 'transferstatuscode': 1}, 
                        {'pmdruleid': 10160, 'createdby': 'Ad hoc Script - PHARMMD\\Jake.Woods', 'updatedby': None, 'transferstatuscode': 1}, 
                        {'pmdruleid': 10016, 'createdby': 'Ad hoc Script - PHARMMD\\Jake.Woods', 'updatedby': None, 'transferstatuscode': 1}, 
                        {'pmdruleid':111, 'createdby': 'Ad hoc Script - PHARMMD\\Jake.Woods', 'updatedby': None, 'transferstatuscode': 1}, 
                        {'pmdruleid': 111, 'createdby': 'Ad hoc Script - PHARMMD\\Jake.Woods', 'updatedby': None, 'transferstatuscode': 1}, 
                        {'pmdruleid': 10020, 'createdby': 'Ad hoc Script - PHARMMD\\Jake.Woods', 'updatedby': None, 'transferstatuscode': 1}]

rulenames = [{'pmdruleid': 112, 'createdby': 'Ad hoc Script - PHARMMD\\Jake.Woods', 'updatedby': None, 'transferstatuscode': 1}, 
             {'pmdruleid': 10160, 'createdby': 'Ad hoc Script - PHARMMD\\Jake.Woods', 'updatedby': None, 'transferstatuscode': 1}]

if len(activeclientrulelist) > 0:
  for rule in rulenames:
     matching_active_client_rule_items = [y for y in activeclientrulelist if y['pmdruleid'] == rule['pmdruleid']
```

Expected output

```
[{'pmdruleid': 112, 'createdby': 'Ad hoc Script - PHARMMD\\Jake.Woods', 'updatedby': None, 'transferstatuscode': 1}, 
 {'pmdruleid': 10160, 'createdby': 'Ad hoc Script - PHARMMD\\Jake.Woods', 'updatedby': None, 'transferstatuscode': 1}]
```

Comment: can you add the expected output

Comment: Added expected output

Comment: From where did `'pmdruleid': 112` come from? It is not in neither of the dicts...

Comment: Edited the question. Please check

Comment: What do you mean *"I am getting `None`"*? Your code has a syntax error...

Comment: I'm not sure how the expected output variable is called `t`, but `matching_active_client_rule_items=...` overwrites that variable in all iterations, so it will contain matches only for the last item of `rulenames`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find the intersection between the 2 lists of dictionaries you could do:

```
res = [x for x in activeclientrulelist if x in rulenames]
```

And `res` will be:

```
[{'pmdruleid': 112, 'createdby': 'Ad hoc Script - PHARMMD\\Jake.Woods', 'updatedby': None, 'transferstatuscode': 1}, {'pmdruleid': 10160, 'createdby': 'Ad hoc Script - PHARMMD\\Jake.Woods', 'updatedby': None, 'transferstatuscode': 1}]
```

And if you only want to consider `pmdruleid` key you can do, no need to loop the `rulenames` outside the list-comprhension other wise you overwrite the results:

```
[x for x in activeclientrulelist for y in rulenames if x['pmdruleid'] == y['pmdruleid']]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is that the list gets refreshed everytime,so I changed it as follows:

```
matching_active_client_rule_items=[]
if len(activeclientrulelist) > 0:
  for rule in rulenames:
     matching_active_client_rule_items.extend( [y for y in activeclientrulelist if y['pmdruleid'] == rule['pmdruleid']])



print(matching_active_client_rule_items)
```

I defined an empty list above and extended the list by the correct item.

Comment: you are right , i edited it.

Answer (score 0):

You have couple of problems with your current code:

1. You have a missing `]` at the end in line `matching_active_client_rule_items = [y for y in activeclientrulelist if y['pmdruleid'] == rule['pmdruleid']`.
2. With this line: `matching_active_client_rule_items = [y for y in activeclientrulelist if y['pmdruleid'] == rule['pmdruleid']`, you are overriding a the list object with only the output of the last item in `rulenames`.

You need to create a list and extend that to fix the code:

```
matching_active_client_rule_items = []
if len(activeclientrulelist) > 0:
  for rule in rulenames:
     matching_active_client_rule_items.extend([y for y in activeclientrulelist if y['pmdruleid'] == rule['pmdruleid']])
```

Although this works, you should be using the list comprehension approach as below to get the intersection of the two lists:

```
matching_active_client_rule_items = [x for x in activeclientrulelist for y in rulenames if x['pmdruleid'] == y['pmdruleid']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```py
activeclientrulelist = [{'pmdruleid': 112, 'createdby': 'Ad hoc Script - PHARMMD\\Jake.Woods', 'updatedby': None, 'transferstatuscode': 1}, 
                        {'pmdruleid': 10160, 'createdby': 'Ad hoc Script - PHARMMD\\Jake.Woods', 'updatedby': None, 'transferstatuscode': 1}, 
                        {'pmdruleid': 10016, 'createdby': 'Ad hoc Script - PHARMMD\\Jake.Woods', 'updatedby': None, 'transferstatuscode': 1}, 
                        {'pmdruleid':111, 'createdby': 'Ad hoc Script - PHARMMD\\Jake.Woods', 'updatedby': None, 'transferstatuscode': 1}, 
                        {'pmdruleid': 111, 'createdby': 'Ad hoc Script - PHARMMD\\Jake.Woods', 'updatedby': None, 'transferstatuscode': 1}, 
                        {'pmdruleid': 10020, 'createdby': 'Ad hoc Script - PHARMMD\\Jake.Woods', 'updatedby': None, 'transferstatuscode': 1}]

rulenames = [{'pmdruleid': 112, 'createdby': 'Ad hoc Script - PHARMMD\\Jake.Woods', 'updatedby': None, 'transferstatuscode': 1}, 
             {'pmdruleid': 10160, 'createdby': 'Ad hoc Script - PHARMMD\\Jake.Woods', 'updatedby': None, 'transferstatuscode': 1},
             {'pmdruleid': 101, 'createdby': 'Ad hoc Script - PHARMMD\\Jake.Woods', 'updatedby': None, 'transferstatuscode': 1}]

result = [check for check in rulenames for rule in activeclientrulelist if rule['pmdruleid']==check['pmdruleid']]
print(result)
```

In this case, the `rulenames`: `'pmdruleid': 101` does not belong to the dictionaries in `activeclientrulelist`, hence omitted!